# OnClickListener() implementation of Array Of Buttons in Android

Tags: android

I am writing an Android Application which outputs some  array of buttons dynamically.
My question is how to implement onClickListener() functionality for Array Of Buttons.
I mean how to recognize the button that is clicked in public void onClick() method ?
I need to display a toast based  on the button that is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

The onClick() method is passed the View that was clicked...

```
public void onClick(View v) {
...
}
```

Use v.getId() to return the button's identifier.

Answer (score 1):

you could create a class derived from `OnClickListener`, that, in the constructor, takes the button ID.

Something like:

```
class MyClickListener extends OnClickListener() {
    int buttonId;  

    MyClickListener(int id) {  
        buttonId = id;  
    }  

    protected void onClick(View v) {  
        ... // do something with buttonId
    }  
}
```

Then, in your `onCreate`, you would do:

```
int i, nb = mButtons.size(); // if mButtons is a List<Button>
for (i = 0; i < nb; i++) {
    mButtons.get(i).setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener(i));
}
```

Comment: Benoit Duffez .Very Good.Nice